# tkinter set a maximum number of button clicks

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I'm making a simple guessing game using tkinter for my python class and was wondering if there was a way to loop it so that the player would have a maximum number of guesses before the program tells the player what the number was and changes the number, or kill the program after it tells them the answer. Heres my code so far:

```
# This program is a number guessing game using tkinter gui.

# Import all the necessary libraries.
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import random

# Set the variables.
number = random.randint(1,80)
attempts = 0

# Start coding the GUI
class numbergameGUI:
    def __init__(self):

        # Create the main window.
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        # Create four frames to group widgets.
        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame()
        self.mid_frame1 = tkinter.Frame()
        self.mid_frame2 = tkinter.Frame()
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame()

        # Create the widget for the top frame.
        self.top_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, \
                    text='The number guessing game!')

        # Pack the widget for the top frame.
        self.top_label.pack(side='left')

        # Create the widgets for the upper middle frame
        self.prompt_label = tkinter.Label(self.mid_frame1, \
                    text='Guess the number I\'m thinking of:')
        self.guess_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.mid_frame1, \
                                        width=10)

        # Pack the widgets for the upper middle frame.
        self.prompt_label.pack(side='left')
        self.guess_entry.pack(side='left')

        # Create the widget for the bottom middle frame.
        self.descr_label = tkinter.Label(self.mid_frame2, \
                    text='Your Guess is:')

        self.value = tkinter.StringVar()

        # This tells user if guess was too high or low.
        self.guess_label = tkinter.Label(self.mid_frame2, \
                                    textvariable=self.value)

        # Pack the middle frame's widgets.
        self.descr_label.pack(side='left')
        self.guess_label.pack(side='left')

        # Create the button widgets for the bottom frame.
        self.guess_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, \
                                     text='Guess', \
                                     command=self.guess,)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, \
                                text='Quit', \
                                command=self.main_window.destroy)

        # Pack the buttons.
        self.guess_button.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

        # Pack the frames
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.mid_frame1.pack()
        self.mid_frame2.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        # Enter the tkinter main loop.
        tkinter.mainloop()

    # Define guess

    def guess(self):

        # Get the number they guessed.
        guess1 = int(self.guess_entry.get())
        # sattempts +=1
        # Tell player too low if their guess was too low.
        if guess1 < number:
            self.value.set('too low')

        # Tell player too high if their guess was too high.
        elif guess1 > number:
            self.value.set('too high')

        # End the loop if the player attempts the correct number.
        if guess1 == number:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Result', 'Congratulations! You guessed right!')

start = numbergameGUI()
```

I tried to put a while loop inside of the guess function because I did that before the program was using tkinter but I haven't been able to get it to work yet.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a while loop. Simply keep a counter variable that you increment after every try. When the variable gets passed a certain threshold, stop the game.

Comment: I had thought of that but where would I Put the counter+=1 at? (To make it increment every time the button is pressed) would I define a whole new function called counter and add a second command to the button(if I can?)?

Comment: @Trey: put it in `guess`

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
def guess(self):
    self.num_guesses += 1

    # Get the number they guessed.
    guess1 = int(self.guess_entry.get())
    # sattempts +=1
    # Tell player too low if their guess was too low.
    if guess1 < number:
        self.value.set('too low')

    # Tell player too high if their guess was too high.
    elif guess1 > number:
        self.value.set('too high')

    # End the loop if the player attempts the correct number.
    if guess1 == number:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Result', 'Congratulations! You guessed right!')
        self.main_window.quit()
    elif self.num_guesses >= self.max_guesses:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Bye Bye', "That's all the guesses you get")
        self.main_window.quit()
```

Comment: Ahh of course why didn't I think of that. Thank You!